# How to print a line break in a loop in Plain TeX?

Tags: line-breaking, plain-tex, loops

Let's say I have this simple loop:

```
\newcount\u\u1
\loop
    \the\u~
    \ifnum\u<2
        \advance\u1
\repeat
```

This prints the numbers as

> 1 2

What I want to achieve is

> 1
>   2

To do so I tried adding `\\` anywhere in the loop, but that gives the error "! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \\". Inserting `\par` gives "! Paragraph ended before \loop was complete".
So the question: How to insert linebreaks/linefeeds/enters/newlines in a loop in Plain Tex?

Comment: Use `\endgraf` instead of `\par`.

Comment: Well that was... quick. Quicker than I expected. It worked, thank you!

Comment: `\endgraf` is end paragarph rather than linebreak, linebreak is `\break` in plain tex (set on zero `\parskip` to see a difference)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `plain.tex`, `\loop...\repeat` is defined as:

```
\def\loop#1\repeat{\def\body{#1}\iterate}
```

so you cannot use `\par` inside it.

Also, in `plain.tex`, the `\\` control sequence does not have the same "break line here" meaning as in LaTeX, so it doesn't work either.

You have two options:

First, redefine `\loop...\repeat` as a long macro:

```
\long\def\loop#1\repeat{\def\body{#1}\iterate}
```

so you can put `\par` in its argument.

Second, use `\endgraf`, which is exactly the same as TeX's primitive `\par`, except that when scanning the argument to a macro TeX looks for `\par`, but not `\endgraf`, so it can be used in these cases.

---

Have in mind that using `\endgraf` does a paragraph break, not a line break, as David said in the comments. Using `\endgraf` will insert a `\parskip` glue between each number. For an actual *line* break, see David's answer :)

Comment: For anyone wondering... the reason why `\par` isn't allowed in macro parameters is because it allows containing errors caused by a missing closing brace in a macro definition to the paragraph where they happen. See pg. 205 of the TexBook. Also Exercise 20.9 explores further how you can/can't "hide" a `\par` in a parameter anyway.

Answer (score 4):

```
\newcount\u\u1

\parindent0pt


\loop
    \the\u
    \ifnum\u<2
        \hfill\break
        \advance\u1
\repeat


\bye
```